# Java version issues with nREPL server and clojure, Tricky version/compatibility issue

Tags: java, emacs, clojure, compatibility, nrepl

This is the error specifically:

error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: Could not transfer artifact refactor-nrepl:refactor-nrepl:jar:2.5.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Could not transfer artifact refactor-nrepl:refactor-nrepl:jar:2.5.0 from/to clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Failed to read artifact descriptor for refactor-nrepl:refactor-nrepl:jar:2.5.0

This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.

If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.

error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: Could not transfer artifact refactor-nrepl:refactor-nrepl:jar:2.5.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Could not transfer artifact refactor-nrepl:refactor-nrepl:jar:2.5.0 from/to clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Failed to read artifact descriptor for refactor-nrepl:refactor-nrepl:jar:2.5.0

This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.

If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.

I'm not behind a proxy. What is the issue here exactly? I've gotten this as a new issue when I changed out my java version for an open jdk version 8. So, it's related to that. It DOES get farther then a previous java exception error I was getting before. I'm very certain this has something to do with it but am not sure what exactly is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

What command did you try to execute?

When I do this:

```clj
clj -Sdeps '{:deps {refactor-nrepl {:mvn/version "2.5.0"}}}'
```

it works just fine (and gives me a REPL with that dependency).

Comment: I'm using the cider-jack-in command on my spacemacs version of emacs.

Comment: Then I think the key words are InvalidAlgorithmParameterException and trustAnchors. It sounds like a Java configuration problem, not especially Clojure-related.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: It was Java bs. Make sure to have your dependencies in a good position. I was using the "recommended" version 8 and prior to that version 11 long term support versions. Those sucked. I was using their OpenJDK equivalents, those sucked. I switched to the OpenJDK latest version (15) and that did the trick. So basically, it was a whole dependency issue...sigh.